# conditional in beforeunload based on user's choice to leave or stay

Tags: javascript, events

Is there any way to execute different functions in a `beforeunload` event listener, based on whether the user chooses to leave the page or not?

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
  // if (user chooses to leave) 
    func1(); // a value is sent to database
  // else if (user chooses to stay on the page)
    func2(); // actually nothing happens
});
```

Comment: you can use a ajax call inside the function1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why use beacon api when it does not provide a response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56789659/why-use-beacon-api-when-it-does-not-provide-a-response)

Comment: Hi, how do you decide whenever user is leaving or staying ? Please clarify your question :)